# nearest neighbour graph, euclidean distance and graph Laplacian

Tags: euclidean-geometry, graph-laplacian

It could be a very simple problem and someone will prove an answer in a second. So, I have unlabelled data points $\left((-2,0),(-1,-1),(0,0),(1,1),(2,0)\right)$ and would like to to the following:

1. Draw 2-nearest neighbour graph with respect to the euclidean distance.
2. Give the graph Laplacian for the same data set.

Can someone help me out here and provide detailed process of creating these graphs?

Thanks